# How was this formula for differentiation derived?

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

[![enter image description here][1]][1]Please tell me how this formula for numerical differentiation derived. I think it has something to do with Vandermonde Matrices but I am not quite sure how to go on from there.

$$ d_{n+1,i,j} = \frac{(-1)^{i-j+1}}{j-i} \frac{i!(n-i)!}{j!(n-j)!}, \quad i,j=0,1, \dots, n \text{ and } j \neq i $$

$$ f'(x_i)= \frac 1 h \sum_{j=0}^n d_{n+1,i,j} f(x_j)+ O _{n,i}\left(h^n\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

You get the Vandermonde matrix by writing the Taylor polynomials
$$
f(x_j)=f(x_i)+f'(x_i)(j-i)h+···+\frac1{n!}f^{(n)}(x_i)(j-i)^nh^n+O(h^{n+1})
$$
in matrix form 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
f(x_0)\\f(x_1)\\\vdots\\f(x_n)
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&(0-i)&(0-i)^2&···&(0-i)^n\\
1&(1-i)&(1-i)^2&···&(1-i)^n\\
\vdots&&&···&\vdots\\
1&(n-i)&(n-i)^2&···&(n-i)^n
\end{bmatrix}
·
\begin{bmatrix}
f(x_i)\\f'(x_i)h\\\frac12f''(x_i)h^2\\\vdots\\\frac1{n!}f^{(n)}(x_i)h^n
\end{bmatrix}+O(h^{n+1})
$$
and solve for the second component $f'(x_i)$.

---

Alternatively you can start with the complete solution of that system, the Lagrange interpolation formula
$$
L(x)=\sum_{j=0}^nL_j(x)f(x_j),\qquad L_j(x)=\prod_{m\ne j}\frac{x-x_m}{x_j-x_m}
$$
to get 
$$
f'(x_j)+O(h^n)=L'(x_i)=\sum_{j=0}^nL_j'(x_i)f(x_j),\qquad L_j'(x_i)=\begin{cases}
\frac1{x_j-x_i}\prod_{m\ne j}\frac{x_i-x_m}{x_j-x_m},&i\ne j,\\
\sum_{m\ne i}\frac1{x_i-x_m},&j=i.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Kind sir, please have a look at the photo that I've attached above. This formula is not based on Lagrange. This is a different approach. My apologies for the bad quality of the photo.